# How would we use object notation to show the first 4 rows of a column in dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dot-notation

How would we use object notation or dot notation to show the first 4 rows of a column in dataframe in pandas? Hope anyone can help please. Thanks

Comment: `df['mycol'].head(4)` or `df.mycol.head(4)`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.